# Self Joining ActiveRecord, Parent_Post_ID and me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self-join

So I have a self-joining model defined. Basically a post on a forum, and a parent_post that it belongs to.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies, :class_name => "Post"
  belongs_to :thread, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "parent_post_id"
end
```

Which seems fundamentally sound. I created a new RESTful route for the reply action, and an action and view.

Routes:

```
  resources :forums do
    resources :posts do
      member do
        get 'reply'
      end
    end
  end
```

The view layer and the control action seems to be where I'm getting hosed up.

```
def reply
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @post = @forum.posts.build
  @post.thread = @forum.posts.find(params[:id])
  @post.title = "RE: #{@post.thread.title}"
end

def create
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @post = @forum.posts.build(params[:post])
  @post.user = current_user
  if @post.save
    redirect_to forum_post_path(@forum, @post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

And in the view layer I was just trying to use the same scaffold generated form partial I'm using for the standard new and edit actions.

```
#reply.html.erb
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>

#_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [@forum,@post], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><h1>New Thread</h1></legend>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field span9' %>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area span9' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', forum_posts_path(@forum), :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

However, the parent_post_id is getting lost when I'm creating the post and it's getting set to nil. Do I need to create another action? Is there some other way to set the thread? Some third thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

Reply action:

```
@forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
@post = @forum.posts.build
@post.thread = @forum.posts.find(params[:id])
@post.title = "RE: #{@post.thread.title}"
```

Then add this to your view

```
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_post_id, @post.thread.id %>
```

BTW I question whether you need a custom `reply` method as opposed to using built-in RESTful methods but this should fix your problem and that wasn't really your question.

Comment: My thinking was that i would be distinguishing between the creation of a new thread versus a reply, but that may be erroneous, should I just add this logic to new and call it a day?

Comment: It seems to me that the only difference is that one (reply post) will have a parent_id and the other (new post) will not.  Both are just involving creating a new post.  If the differences got more complicated you could consider having a thread controller.  My main suggestion was to question yourself as to the necessity of adding custom methods to RESTful routes.  If you find yourself doing it you might need to consider the need for another controller.

Comment: Wow, the `thread` controller idea actually made me think of a completely opposite idea. Why not a `reply` controller? I'll post what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :forum_id , @forum.id %>
```

to your form

Answer (score 0):

So basically, when you're submitting to the `Posts#create` action you're submitting a url that looks something like this `/forum/1/posts` which removes the `parent_post_id` from the url. Since you're using that `parent_post_id` to build that url, you need a way to `POST` with it.

My suggestion is allowing a `POST` to a `reply` resource that is nested in the `posts` resource.
(ie `POST /forums/1/posts/1/reply`)

So maybe something like this

```
resources :forums do
  resources :posts do
    # :show is actually just pointing to a form 
    resource :reply, :only => [:show, :create], 
                     :controller => 'reply' #otherwise gets routed to 'replies'
  end
end
```

So you would also need a `ReplyController` but that would basically match your `reply` method on your post controller with a few changes.

```
def show
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @post = @forum.posts.find(params[:post_id])
  @reply = @forum.posts.build
  @reply.thread = @post
  @reply.title = "RE: #{@post.thread.title}"
end

def create
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @post = @forum.posts.find(params[:post_id])
  @reply = @forum.posts.build(params[:reply])
  @reply.thread = @post
  @reply.user = current_user
  if @reply.save
    redirect_to forum_post_path(@forum, @post), notice: 'Reply was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "show"
  end
end
```

The biggest problem would be that you would have to abstract your `Post` fields from your `form for` block. That's because the url you're trying to `POST` to is going to be different. But it shouldn't be too bad just doing something like this:

**reply/show.html.erb**

```
<%= 
  form_for @reply, :url => forum_post_reply_path(@forum, @post), 
                   :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |builder|
%>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><h1>New Reply</h1></legend>

    <%= render "posts/post_fields", :f => builder %>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= builder.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', forum_post_path([@forum, @post]), :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

<% end %>
```

**posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@forum,@post], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |builder| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><h1>New Thread</h1></legend>

    <%= render "post_fields", :f => builder %>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= builder.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', forum_posts_path(@forum), :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**posts/_post_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field span9' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area span9' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: There's probably a better way to declare the routes than I have, but I don't really know.*